# wordpress - display subcategory siblings when viewing a single post

Tags: php, wordpress

Thank you all for a great site. I'm learning a lot. I'm trying to get my subcategory siblings to show when a single post is clicked on.  I have set up my parent categories using the wordpress menu. I am using a php widget to call for the children (subcategories) in a separate menu (and then style with CSS). The code I'm using is showing the specific (relevant) children when each category is clicked on; however I am unable to figure out how to make them appear when viewing a post.

```
    <?php
```

if(is_category()) {

```
$breakpoint = 0;
$thiscat = get_term( get_query_var('cat') , 'category' );
$subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.get_query_var('cat') );

if(empty($subcategories) && $thiscat->parent != 0) {
    $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.$thiscat->parent.'' );
}

$items='';
if(!empty($subcategories)) {
    foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
        if($thiscat->term_id == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
        $items .= '
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$subcat->term_id.$current.'">
            <a href="'.get_category_link( $subcat->term_id ).'" title="'.$subcat->description.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a>
        </li>';
    }
    echo "<ul>$items</ul>";
}
unset($subcategories,$subcat,$thiscat,$items);
```

}
?>

I'm attempting to mimic the behavior of this [menu](http://thepioneerwoman.com/blog/2011/05/sorting-cattle-by-marlboro-man/) at pioneer woman.com

Any help or a better solution would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lists all child categories of the current post's category:

```
<?php
    echo '<ul>';
    $post_child_cat = array();
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
        $args = array( 'child_of' => $cat->cat_ID );
        $categories = get_categories( $args );
        if( $categories ) foreach( $categories as $category ) {
            echo '<li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$category->term_id.'">'.
            '<a title="'.$category->description.'" href="';
            echo bloginfo('url');
            echo '/category/'.$cat->slug.'/'.$category->slug.'">'.
            $category->name.'</a></li>'; 
        }
    }
   echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. This works perfect and was just what I needed.